# CodeIgniter ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, url-routing

```
 function new_review(){
    $.post('restaurant_profile/get_dg_new_restaurant_review', {}, function callback(response) {
          alert(response);
    }
 }
```

Hi I have a function that does an jQuery ajax post to a controller function. The function outputs a simple string using the PHP `echo` function.

The function works fine if I don't have any URI segments after the controller name in initial page load.

```
ex: mysite.com/index.php/test_controller/
```

If for example the page was loaded with a index function and the URI segment contained the index function

```
ex: mysite.com/index.php/test_controller/index
```

The response from the controller is all of the string output from the index function.
this is entire page HTML. I only want the text from the `et_dg_new_restaurant_review` function

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

actually i figured it out.
the post url must be the full url

http://www.mystite.com/index.php/restaurant_profile/get_dg_new_restaurant_review

Answer (score 0):

actually it does not need a full url, you can try this:

```
"/index.php/restaurant_profile/get_dg_new_restaurant_review"
```

if you have done the Route Rewrite (to hide/remove the need of index.php), you can use this:

```
"/restaurant_profile/get_dg_new_restaurant_review"
```

jsut remember to start your url with "/"